# Galaxy Grand 2 asks password for credential storage while trying to create a vpn

Tags: vpn, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I have never used the vpn feature of my phone. Now when I try to create a vpn, by going to

> settings > more networks > vpn

it asks me to enter password for credential storage which I have never set. I haven't set lock screen in my device. I have just used applock software to lock some of my application and which I am sure is not the reason for this. Please help me solve this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to use a pattern, PIN or password lock screen in order to configure and use VPNs.** This is a limitation in Android which may seem stupid and annoying, but there are reasons for it:

- The credentials storage has to be encrypted with a password, so that even if other apps are able to steal the files they would be useless.
- VPNs are primarily used at corporations that allow employees to work from home. The servers on their network often contain sensitive information that could easily be compromised if someone would steal your phone and connect to the VPN.

Comment: But that's not what he's asking about. The issue, as I understand it (since I'm having the same problem) is that when he tries to set it up, he's being prompted to "Enter the password for credential storage", when he never set a password for the credential storage in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I see. Does `Settings > Security > Clear credentials` help? It should reset credential storage so I assume you could enter a new password. I'm now just fumbling around in the dark because I never had this problem.

Comment: Well, entering the wrong password too many times would also do that. But what's driving me crazy is, where the devil are these passwords coming from if we never set them? I also get prompted for an encryption password when I try to do an adb backup, but I never set a backup password, and my device is not encrypted! I also tried every lockout screen password I've ever used, which are the only passwords I've ever set for the device.

Comment: Thank you @matega . I haven't set any lock screen password previously and when I did, it solved the problem

Comment: @Adi Inbar, maybe those dialogs are badly worded. I think the phone is asking you to **set** a backup password with which the backup will be encrypted, not verifying if you know the password. Also the same case with the VPN  credentials storage problem. Have you tried just entering a new password?

Comment: Late to the party, but a little hint still: If you don't want that enforcement, and your device is rooted, the Xposed Framework offers a solution with its [Lockscreen Disabler](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.lr.keyguarddisabler) addon. Whether that's a good idea is a decision everyone needs to make for him/herself, ad definitely depends on the use-case.